# Best Way to make my Ubuntu portable

Tags: backup, restore, installed-programs, portable

recently I had some issues backing up my Ubuntu and I would like to know if there is any recommendation to make it more portable, for example:

- Should I install everything that is possible Within my home folder?
- Any good program (or code) to backup all installed programs in a way they can be used to restore another installation? And maybe another OS version?

Cheers,

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way of making your files and configuration portable (as you say) is to have an exclusive partition for your **/home** folder. That way you would be able to install and reinstall Ubuntu as many times you wish, and all your configuration will be intact.

Comment: This seems to be asking about how to keep installed applications, so that might not help.